# Replace the column name in the magento collection while loading it

Tags: magento

I have a custom module and I am loading a collection like following

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/product')->getCollection()
                                   ->addFieldToFilter('sku',$sku);
```

There is field named as `prod_id` in the database. Can I get this as `entity_id` while loading the collection?

If yes. Please help how to do this.

Comment: try to change _construct function in module Resource file...
app/code/[Package]/[Module]/Model/Resource/[Module]
$this->_init('module/module', 'prod_id');

Comment: have you find solution?

Comment: @KeyurShah no, actually problem is search functionality in my custom module Grid throws error saying column entity_id does not exist.But in my database tables  in am not having any such column.So I was thinking if I can use column name alias kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all all

```
addAttributeToFilter()  is used to filter EAV collections.

addFieldToFilter() is used to filter Non-EAV collections.
```

EAV-models are for example product, customer, sales, etc so you can use use `addAttributeToFilter()` for those entities.

```
addFieldToFilter() is mapped to `addAttributeToFilter()` for `EAV` entities. So you can just use `addFieldToFiler().`
```

You can have a look in `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php` where the Mapping is done:

```
public function addFieldToFilter($attribute, $condition = null) {
    return $this->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition);
}
```

---

If you are using custom module then you can directly use `addFieldToFilter()` with your `column` name

Like

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection()
                                   ->addFieldToFilter('column_name',$data);
```

Let me know if you have any query